# Draw line with inner element in draggable + jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

see below image.

[image]

our Que : when one dragable element moving at this time compare inner element and check 8 side point and same line then draw line in between this two point.

i use jquery ui and jquery1.8.

so please help me . how to implement this idea in jquery ui?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is http://jsplumb.org/ for this purpose.

Great and powerful libary.
It's not jQuery UI, but it's looks also nice!